# how to push an element using a useState in a specific key nested?

Tags: reactjs

I need to do a push on my `setMiObj` but I don't know how to do something like `setMiObj.numbers.push(123)`:

my output desired:

```
{ numbers: [22,123],name:"John Doe" }
```

how can I do it?

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const [miObj, setMiObj] = useState({ numbers: [22],name:"John Doe" });
  return (
    <div className="App">
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do something like

```
setMiObj({...miObj,numbers:[...miObj.numbers,123]})
```

If you want different people I would store the state as an array of objects. So every object would be `{ numbers: [],name:"John Doe" }`. Your code would look like this :

```
const [miObj, setMiObj] = useState([{ numbers: [],name:"John Doe" }]);
```

instead of this

```
const [miObj, setMiObj] = useState({ numbers: [],name:"John Doe" });
```

Notice the `[]` surrounding the object.

Now that you have an array of objects, you can leverage the `...` operator to do this. It's pretty clean.
Let's say the state already has something like this
`[{ numbers: [123],name:"John Doe" }]` and you want to append Jane's so it would like this `{ numbers: [123],name:"John Doe" }`

Here's what it would look like:

```
setMiObj([...miObj,{"numbers" : [214], "name":"Jane Smith"}])
```

The `...` will expand all the previous state objects and also add Jane Smith's object to it!

Comment: thanks crack, I dont understand why `numbers:[... miObj.numbers,123]` this piece of code add `123` ?

Comment: This code is essentially setting miObj state to the old state then replacing the numbers key with the value of the old number and 123. Basically, we're abusing the fact that we can't have 2 keys with the same name under the same object. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do not use push. That is what setState is for. For your question, you can use prevState inside your useState

something like

```
setMiObj(prevState => ({
                ...prevState,
                [numbers]: 123
            }));
```

basically we're telling react that we keep the previous state but change numbers.

Comment: Note that my solution is if you want to change the value of a key inside an object while keeping the other values. If you want to add another object inside an array while keeping the previous objects, then @DavidHarvey 's solution is what you need.

Comment: My idea es maintains my structure, but if I need to maintain my previous data inside of `numbers`, what can I do?

Comment: Then David Harvey's first suggestion should do the trick